# Generating JSON stream in PHP and displaying it as Google Chart

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have problem find any useful documentation on this topic, so I decided to ask here.

I try to create streamed JSON from external data. My current code is this:

```
<?php 

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
ob_implicit_flush(true);
echo '{"points":[';
for($i = 0, $j = 100; ; $i+=2, $j-=3) {
    $data = '{"x":'.$i .',"y":'.$j.'}';

    if($i >= $j){
        echo $data . "]}";
        break;
    }
    echo $data . ", ";
    sleep(1);
    ob_flush();
}
?>
```

The data will eventually come from elsewhere, but this cycle will suffice for now. Output is this:

```
{"points":[{"x":0,"y":100}, {"x":2,"y":97}, {"x":4,"y":94}, {"x":6,"y":91}, {"x":8,"y":88}, {"x":10,"y":85}, {"x":12,"y":82}, {"x":14,"y":79}, {"x":16,"y":76}, {"x":18,"y":73}, {"x":20,"y":70}, {"x":22,"y":67}, {"x":24,"y":64}, {"x":26,"y":61}, {"x":28,"y":58}, {"x":30,"y":55}, {"x":32,"y":52}, {"x":34,"y":49}, {"x":36,"y":46}, {"x":38,"y":43}, {"x":40,"y":40}]}
```

but, as you can see, it comes "one point at a time" (real data also will). I have a feeling that this is not treated as proper JSON, but I can't figure out how to use *json_encode()* for this purpose. Then I try to display it on client side via AJAX and Google Charts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php $property->getProperty('applicationPage',$_SESSION['lang'],'title') ?></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "getData.php",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
            }).responseText;

        var options = {
            title: 'Graf',
            curveType: 'function',
            legend: { position: 'bottom' },
            width: 500,
            height: 500
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('div_chart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I can't make it work. Now I don't know if I messed up only Google Charts drawing, the JSON generating or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget some litle things.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php $property->getProperty('applicationPage',$_SESSION['lang'],'title') ?></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "getData.php",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
            }).responseText;
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

            var options = {
                title: 'Graf',
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                width: 500,
                height: 500
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('div_chart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div_chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and your json shall look like this

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataview-class

Comment: Thanks for answer. Chart is now working (adjusted JSON generator, added missing lines of code), but I have another problem. It isn't drawing the chart real-time ("before your eyes"), instead it waits for all data to come and then display the chart. Is there any way to achieve this "real time" chart redraw?

Comment: do you know how to use node.js and socket.io ?

Comment: maybe you could use js setInerval function. to call drawChart function every n time in ms

Comment: `setInterval` is not a viable option. It blocks out whole page in combination with loading JSON via jQuery AJAX. My first idea was to use Websockets or SSE, but I don't have a clue how to interpret that data, so now I am trying compel Google Charts to refresh my chart properly via AJAX.